# The Relationship Between Topological Space and Fundamental Group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am just an Algebraic Topology beginner and I have one doubt related to the relationship between the topological space and the fundamental group. As we know that if given a  specific topological space, we can calculate the fundamental group of it. Therefore, my question is that if given a fundamental group, can we define a particular topological space for it? How?

I hope you do not mind me and provide me with some intuitions on this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this an extremely well-studied question. You can find it an Appendix of the book by Hatcher or a more general construction [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space).

Comment: @ThePuix Thanks for helping me !

Comment: He asked me this question since I recently finished the fundamental group calculation and started to do on covering spaces. He also specified that we can define a particular topological space for it, but I still do not know how.